# OpenCV python search within contour

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Python3 with OpenCV for a project. I am using a camera to take a image from a aerial position. There are 3 different color squares that are touching, with a muddled background. I am able to eliminate the entire background, and get a single contour that encompasses the 3 squares.

How can I search within that contour to determine what color square is which?

```
  def filter_size(self, pixel_size):
    _, cnt, _ = cv2.findContours(self.processed_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for c in cnt:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) > pixel_size:
            self.countours.append(c)  #  contains my found contours
```

[image: Contour]

I want to be able to use my HSV filters within that contour to label each one of the squares by it's color.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: You can mention the color ranges of the basic colors and try searching if that color is present or not

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes, but how do I specify the bounds to just be within my contour?

Comment: Use an online color code converter [LIKE THIS](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm)

Comment: @JeruLuke I do think you're missing my point. I don't want to search the entire image, just within the small contour. I know how to filter colors, just not how to specify location bounds

Comment: OK since you have found the desired contour region, you can mask out the unwanted regions

Comment: Since you want to find what each color is, you further divide the detected contour region into three parts using edge detection/ threshold and find what is present in each of them

Comment: @JeruLuke OK perfect makes sense. How do I mask out an area given a contour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139293/discussion-between-jeru-luke-and-kyle-hunter).

Comment: The chat session is still loading. You can use `cv2.bitwise_and()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you have found the contoured area already you can iterate inside the contour and find new contours which will end up with 3 contours.
2. After that, you can get samples from the center of contours like below.

   `for c in contours: 
       x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)`
3. Since x and y will be your center points for the contour c; finally, all you have to do is applying the HSV mask to center points.